# Microsoft Excel 2013 just stops opening any file

Tags: excel

[image]

[image]

I just could not find why this is happening. It happens at random when we open and close excel/word files.

Comment: this isnt really a question. But I would recommend reinstalling office. Should be no problem.

Comment: Have you searched for **excel there was a problem sending the command to the program** ?